# Using cases without a switch - How does this work?

Tags: javascript

I saw this code on codewars - It reminded me of a `switch` as it has cases yet no switch. How does the cases word work?

```
function basicOp(operation, value1, value2){
  let cases = {
    '+': value1 + value2,
    '-': value1 - value2,
    '*': value1 * value2,
    '/': value1 / value2
  };
  return cases[operation]
}
```

Comment: it's just a variable called `cases`. Pretend it's called `mathOperations` and it becomes immediately obvious you're just returning an object property lookup.

Comment: @Mike Oh lord haha thanks i couldnt see that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function basicOp(operation, value1, value2){
  let cases = {
    '+': value1 + value2,
    '-': value1 - value2,
    '*': value1 * value2,
    '/': value1 / value2
  };
  return cases[operation]
}
console.log(basicOp('+', 2, 3))
console.log(basicOp('-', 3, 1))
console.log(basicOp('*', 2, 6))
console.log(basicOp('/', 4, 2))
```

This has nothing to do with `switch`. It's an object with attributes, where the operator is passed as the key in order to get its corresponding value and perform an arithmetic operation.